# Determine whether $(ne^{-(x-n)^2})_{n\in\mathbf{N}}$ is pointwise convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

Determine whether the following functional sequence is pointwise convergent. In the case of convergence, give the limit function and show that the convergence is uniform or that it is
not uniform, as the case may be.

$$(ne^{-(x-n)^2})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$

Current solution:

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

The definition of pointwise convergent states $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$.

As $n\to\infty$, $e^{-(x-n)^2}\to0$

so the function $f_n(x)\to0$ when $n\to\infty$

Thus, $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to the zero function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Not sure how to go about showing whether convergence is uniform or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote $f_n(x) = e^{-(x-n)^2}$ but I think you meant $f_n(x) = \frac{n}{e^{(x-n)^2}}$, and as you said it converges pointwise to $0$. But if we let $x = n$, we have $f_n(x) = n$, which does not converge. So it does not converge uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=f(x).$

$M_n: = \sup_{x \in D} |f_n(x) -f(x)|.$

Then $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $D$  $\iff$

$M_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
(Rudin Chapter 7).

For this problem:

$M_n = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|ne^{-(x-n)^2}| = n.$ (Why?)